# What does Sympys' doit() does on derivatives?

Tags: python, sympy, differentiation

I'm trying to compute higher derivatives of f(y(x)) w.r.t to x using sympys diff.

```
from sympy import *
from IPython.display import display
init_printing(use_latex=True)

x = symbols('x')
f,  y = symbols('f, y', cls=Function)

d2 = diff(f(y(x)),x,2)
print(d2)
print(d2.doit())
```

Sympy returns :

```
Derivative(y(x), x)**2*Derivative(f(y(x)), y(x), y(x)) + Derivative(y(x), x, x)*Subs(Derivative(f(_xi_1), _xi_1), (_xi_1,), (y(x),))

Derivative(f(y(x)), y(x))*Derivative(y(x), x, x) + 2*Derivative(y(x), x)**2*Derivative(f(y(x)), y(x), y(x))
```

Latex image: [Sympy result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OxaK.png).

While the first result seems to be correct, I do not understand the factor 2 in the second expression after the doit() operation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you stumbled upon a bug, which [was just fixed a few weeks ago](//github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12139).

You can test this by substituting `f`, `y`, and `x` with some functions or values respectively (append to your code):

```
f_ex = Lambda(x, x**2)
y_ex = Lambda(x, sin(x))
x_ex = 2

substitutions = [ (f,f_ex), (y,y_ex), (x,x_ex) ]

print( d2.subs(substitutions).doit().n() )        #-1.30728724172722
print( d2.doit().subs(substitutions).doit().n() ) #-0.960930862590836
```

The printed values should be the same.

The issue can be further isolated to:

```
print((Derivative(f(y(x)), x, x)))
print((Derivative(f(y(x)), y(x), y(x))).doit())
```

Here, a plain `doit` simply adds a factor of 2, which is obviously wrong.